# How can I stop 3 media players when I click on a image button?

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, imagebutton

I have 3 media players and I want when I click on ImageButton, all three media players stop at the same time.

Here is my code:

```
private MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);
    final TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1 );
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.two);
            mp.start();
            myText.setText("2");
    final TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2 );
        MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.two);
            mp1.start();
            myText2.setText("2");
    final TextView myText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3 );
        MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.four);
            mp2.start();
            myText3.setText("4");
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   public void onClick(View v)
        {  Intent i = new Intent(Page1Activity.this, Page2Activity.class);     
           startActivity(i);

            if (mp != null) { mp.stop(); mp.release(); mp = null;}
            if (mp1 != null) { mp1.stop(); mp1.release(); mp1 = null;}
            if (mp2 != null) { mp2.stop(); mp2.release(); mp2 = null;}
        } });
```

How can I stop all three media players at the same time?

Comment: Doing same what problem you are facing? and one suggestion move all code related to stop media player before `startActivity(i);`

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thank you. I move them before startActivity but not working and not stop

Comment: @MonaK: `Page2Activity ` Activity is starting on Button click or not?

Comment: @BabulPatel I want stop all three media players, but this code is not working

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes, start on image button

Answer (score 1):

```
private MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);
    final TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1 );
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.two);
            mp.start();
            myText.setText("2");
    final TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2 );
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.two);
            mp1.start();
            myText2.setText("2");
    final TextView myText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3 );
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.four);
            mp2.start();
            myText3.setText("4");
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   public void onClick(View v)
        {  Intent i = new Intent(Page1Activity.this, Page2Activity.class);     
           startActivity(i);

            if (mp != null) { mp.stop(); mp.release(); mp = null;}
            if (mp1 != null) { mp1.stop(); mp1.release(); mp1 = null;}
            if (mp2 != null) { mp2.stop(); mp2.release(); mp2 = null;}
        } });
```

Dude.. you are declaring its two time. Please try this code.

Comment: private MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2;

and 

mp = MediaPlayer.create(Page1Activity.this, R.raw.two);

Comment: @MonaK he declared mediaplayer objects two times.

Comment: Babul I trying to this code but It still does not work and not stop media players